# Can we write $\int_p^\infty\int_q^\infty f(x,y)dxdy=\int_p^\infty\int_q^\infty\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)=F(\infty,\infty)-F(p,q)$?

Tags: probability

Let $(X,Y)$ be non-negative absolutely continuous random vector with density function $f(x,y)$ and distribution function $F(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)=f(x,y).$

Can we write $\int_p^\infty\int_q^\infty f(x,y)dxdy=\int_p^\infty\int_q^\infty\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)=F(\infty,\infty)-F(p,q)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A geometrical interpretation will show that, because $F(p,q)=P(X\lt p \cap Y \lt q)$

$$P(X\gt p \cap Y \gt q)=1-P(X<p)-P(Y<q)+P(X\lt p \cap Y \lt q)\\
=1-F_{X,Y}(p,+\infty)-F_{X,Y}(+\infty,q)+F_{X,Y}(p,q)\\
=1-F_X(p)-F_Y(q)+F_{X,Y}(p,q)$$